# Indent first line of paragraph in Google Docs, but not under heading

Tags: formatting, google-docs

Are there a way to, preferable automatically (rulewise), indent the first line of a paragraph in Google Docs but not doing that for text directly under a heading? 
Example:

```
First heading
Here the line is not indented.
   Here it is
here the text wraps down from its beginning "here it is".
   Here too.
Second heading
Not indented.
   But here.
```

I have seen that there is a way of doing this for all texts, headings included, but that is not what one would want - at least not when writing texts in my native swedish language.

Comment: Is "Here it is" the second line of the paragraph starting with "Here the line is not indented.", or is it a separate paragraph?

Comment: It is the second paragraph - the text after it is supposed to illustrate when the line wraps around the text-window. "Here too" is the next paragraph after that one.

Comment: I would not know how to do it with text formatting tools from the user interface, but it is possible to write a script and run it whenever you want to update the formatting of your already existing text. Are you familiar with Apps Script? https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Comment: Thank you, ziganotschka, for that advice. I will look into that if there are no emidate solution.